# Why are my JS Objects added to Array as undefined values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, return

I have a function that grabs some values from JSON files, and creates an `item` object.

```
var searchIndex = [];

function getSearchTerms(param){

  var filePath = 'json/' + param + '.json';

  $.getJSON(filePath, function( data ) {

      var item = {
        param: param,
        title: data.title,
        person: data.fname + ' ' + data.lname
      };

      // console.log(item);
      // searchIndex.push(item);

      return item;
  });

}
```

I can see the `item` objects with correct properties being created when I check the console.

However, when I try to add the objects to `searchIndex` array, either within the function or within the loop that calls the `getSearchTerms` function, I get an array with the correct number of rows, but all the values are undefined.

```
var contentFiles = [ 'a', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 0; i < contentFiles.length; i++) {
    searchIndex.push( getSearchTerms(contentFiles[i]) );
}
```

What stupid thing am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, reading files from the disk takes a little bit of time. Not a lot, but enough to mess with this little bit of code you're trying to write. Now's a good time for you to learn how to use asynchronous code. Here are some slight alterations to specific lines of code that might be able to help.

```
async function getSearchTerms(param)
await var item
```

within your loop...

```
await getSearchTerms(contentFiles[i])
searchIndex.push(object))
```

I'm no expert, and this is the first SO question I've ever answered. You might need a .next in there or something. If this doesn't work, look further into the concept of async/await functions. In your code, you're pushing objects that haven't gotten their actual value yet, because reading from disk takes a moment. JS travels line by line without waiting, and sometimes you'll have values that need a second to be sorted out.